# Run project imported from GIT

Tags: android, configuration, project, preview

I'm beginner to Android Studio.
I'm following this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#1

In Android Studio, I don't know how to preview, nor launch the project 'BasicLayoutCodelab'..
Here what is looking at:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNGOR.jpg)

How to set up Android Studio to be able to run this imported project?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you have opened the root project.
you should open each directory separate in android studio to recognize it as android project, then you can build and run the project

Answer (score 0):

The link you shared for [CodeLab](https://github.com/android/codelab-android-compose) is a mono repo, Try opening the **[inner folder](https://imgur.com/a/Tn9Mwy0)** in Android Studio as you are in the root project.

Comment: In my screenshoot, you can see I opened the inner folder to be able to edit the file mainActivity.kt

Comment: Go to File> Open> Select the BaseCodeLab Folder